# WSO2 recovery notification always defaulting to passwordReset

Tags: soap, wso2, wso2-identity-server

We are currently trying to use WSO2 to send a recovery email for unlocking newly created user accounts.  To be concise, here are the relevant two lines of Java code which are attempting to do this:

```
String key = userInfoutil.verifyUser("someuser@tenant.com", captchaBean);
userInfoutil.sendRecoveryNotification("someuser@tenant.com", key, "accountUnLock");
```

Here are what the three parameters to `sendRecoveryNotification()` are:

```
someuser@tenant.com - user/tenant to notify
key                 - authorization string based off Captcha
accountUnLock       - email template to use for recovery message
```

However, what we have observed is that the `passwordReset` template always gets used.  In other words, it ignores whatever we specify and sends a password reset email.  We also verified the same behavior when calling the service directly from SOAP UI for the same user.  In addition, when we comment out the `passwordReset` configuration from the `email-admin-config.xml` file, we get a `NullPointerException`.  So it seems that the WSO2 server is hell-bent on using `passwordReset`.

This problem is difficult to diagnose because the code where the exception happens is on the WSO2 server itself, and not in our own code.  As far as we know, we have the configuration correct.

Massive upvote coming to anyone who can even shed light on this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The third parameter in sendRecoveryNotification is not the email template. It is the type of notification that should be sent to the user like email, SMS. By default, Identity Server supports only email.

What is the requirement? Why can't you use passwordReset templates?

Thanks
Isura

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  Assuming I use `email` as the notification type, then how do I specify _which_ email template I want to use?  If we can't choose the template then what would the point of having so many?

Comment: Identity Server decides which template uses for which task. If you are going to use password reset, it picks password reset template, If you want to use self registraion, it takes self registraoin email template, if you want to use ask password feature, it takes ask password template.

Comment: What would the SOAP calls for password reset and account unlock be?  It would seem that we could define a custom template.  But if WSO2 chooses which template to use automatically, then how could we possible use a custom template?

Comment: You can follow [1]. It has answers for all your questions.                                            [1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Recover+with+Notification

Comment: This documentation is for `5.0.0` while we are using `5.1.0`.  In any case, following these steps did not solve the problem.

Comment: @IsuraDilharaKarunaratne We are using RemoteUserStoreManagerClient addUser with ask Password field set to true.How to resend this askPassword email using any api??

Comment: configure ask password properties, according to the documentation and add user with empty password.